# Bootstrap Footer Z-Index

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, z-index, footer

Hello and thanks in advance for the help. Here's a link to the site in question: [caulfield.co/test/](http://caulfield.co/test/)

I'm attempting to create a parallax footer reveal effect using Bootstrap 4. I cannot seem to edit the `z-index` of the `fixed-bottom` `footer`to hide it behind the body `div` so that it reveals only after scrolling to the bottom of the `body` whose `margin-bottom` is equal the height of the `div`. For some reason, when trying to edit the `z-index`, nothing happens. I assume this is something in the CSS of Bootstrap causing this, but don't know where to start to look for it. Can anyone help?

CSS:

```
.body-temp{
  height:1000px;
  margin-bottom:300px;
  background-color:black;
  z-index:5000;
}


/* Footer
-------------------------------------------------- */

footer{
  height:300px;
  background-color:#232323;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:300;
  font-size:.8rem;
  color:#666666;
  z-index: -1000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container body-temp">
  </div>


  <!-- Footer
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
      <footer class="container-fluid fixed-bottom">
        <a class="" href="#">
          <img class="grow" id="footer-logo" src="images/mb-white.svg" alt="Margaret Biggs Fine Art">
        </a>
        <p>&copy; 2018 Margaret Biggs</p>
        <div>
          <a class="footer-icons" href="#">
              <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
          </a>
          <a  class="footer-icons" href="#">
              <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is bootstrap overriding you css via the css specificity.

You added the BS clss `fixed-bottom` that has a `z-index` of 1030.

the selector `footer` wil not overide it.

Use `footer.fixed-bottom` to overide BS via specificity.

On the case of `body-temp`. It has a `position: static`. This wont work with `z-index`. To solve this add `position: relative` on your `body-temp` styles.

[MDN DOCS for z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

> "For a positioned box (that is, one with any position other than static), the z-index property specifies: ..."

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks I thought so. Why doesn't editing the `z-index` of the `body-temp` work, do you know?

Comment: Excellent, yes, it took changing both those issues. Thanks for taking the time! Great answer.

Comment: Awesome. Code on mate!

Answer (score 1):

The quickest and easiest solution is to simply set the position of the .body-temp div like below:

```
.body-temp {
    position: relative;
}
```

That being said, what I would do is wrap your entire .body-temp div in a wrapper, and specify the background color of said wrapper div:

**HTML**

```
<div class="body-wrapper">
    <div class="container body-temp"></div>
</div>
<footer class="container-fluid fixed-bottom">
    <a class="" href="#">
        <img class="grow" id="footer-logo" src="images/mb-white.svg" alt="Margaret Biggs Fine Art">
    </a>
    <p>© 2018 Margaret Biggs</p>
    <div>
        <a class="footer-icons" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="footer-icons" href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
.body-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```